# Columns printed on console not aligned

Tags: java, formatting

I have to read a file and display some data from it. The file to read is:

```
Rory Williams
88
92
78
-1
James Barnes
87
76
91
54
66
-1
Sarah Jane Smith
92
86
95
85
82
-1
Jack Sparrow
18
54
13
0
-1
```

My code to display the person stats is:

```
public static void displayPersonStats(PrintWriter printWriter, String name,
        int average, int median, int max, int min) {
    // print person row
    // printWriter.printf("%s \t\t%d\t%d\t%d\t%d\n", name, average, median,
    // max, min);
    //if min is one digit, it needs to be moved one more space to the right
    if (min < 10) {
        System.out.printf("%s  \t\t   %d      %d    %d     %d\n", name, average, median, max, min);
    //if digit is not one dgit it can follow below pattern
    } else {
        System.out.printf("%s \t\t   %d      %d    %d    %d\n", name, average, median, max, min);
    }
}
```

OUTPUT:

```
Name                     Mean  Median   Max   Min
------------------     ------  ------  ----  ----
Rory Williams              86      88    92    78
James Barnes               74      76    91    54
Sarah Jane Smith                   88      86    95    82
Jack Sparrow               21      15    54     0
```

Right now I'm just printing to the console instead of writing to the file. As you can see the Sarah Jane row is messed up. When I added more names with 3 words it did the same thing. Any help on fixing this is appreciated.

Comment: Linking to a pastebin with all of your code is nice, but please also include the piece of code your question is about in the OP.

Comment: The Sarah Jane row looks fine to me. What's it supposed to say?

Comment: this are the methods, sorry:http://pastebin.com/pvB7DvkF

Comment: @David Conrad, the sarah jane row of numbers are shifted to the right for some reason

Comment: I'm just looking at what you put in your question.

Comment: @DavidConrad do you see what i mean by the sarah jane row being shifted over?

Comment: *Sigh* You can't use tabs like that. Learn how to use `printf` by studying the `String.format()` documentation.

Comment: when i paste the console it gets misformated

Comment: so remove the tabs and put \t?

Comment: @DavidConrad coud you show me a corrected fprintf?

Comment: ergonaut and caps lock already did -- no, no tabs, no `\t` -- tabs BAD

Answer (score 1):

Try printing with formatting:

```
System.out.printf("%-40s", name); ...
```

which would add extra spaces for short names.

Then you also need to change the headings.

Comment: this is what happened when i did that: http://pastebin.com/vnBFZ0g9

Comment: please mark as answered, and update your question with more details.  Don't rely on external sources to host your code.

Answer (score 1):

Like Ergonaut wrote:

```
System.out.printf("%-20s %6d %6d %6d %6d\n", name, average, median, max, min);
```

Your output will be like:

```
Name                     Mean  Median   Max   Min
------------------     ------  ------  ----  ----
Rory Williams            86     88     92     78
James Barnes             74     76     91     54
Sarah Jane Smith         88     86     95     82
Jack Sparrow             21     15     54      0

Total number of participants: 4
Highest average score: Sarah Jane Smith (88)
```